# Why am I getting an "unexpected token" error when returning meta tags for opf file (ePub)?

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I am still building my app for ePub production. At the moment, I am able to generate records for more authors but can’t solve a strange error.

My code:

```
{
    for $i in (1 to 20)
    let $authRequestGivenName := 'authorGivenName' || $i
    let $authRequestSurname := 'authorSurname' || $i
    let $authorGivenName := request:get-parameter($authRequestGivenName, '')
    let $authorSurname := request:get-parameter($authRequestSurname, '')
    return
        if ($authorGivenName)
        then
            <dc:creator id="author{$i}">{$authorGivenName || ' ' || $authorSurname}</dc:creator>
                <meta refines="#author{$i}" property="file-as">{$authorSurname || ', ' $authorGivenName}</meta>
                <meta refines="#author{$i}" property="role" scheme="marc:relators">aut</meta>
                <meta refines="#author{$i}" property="role" scheme="onix:codelist17">A01</meta>
        else ()
}
```

The problem is with those three `<meta/>` lines below the `<dc:creator/>` record. Without them everything works fine. With any of them eXist complains

```
err:XPST0003 error found while loading module epub-util: Error while loading module create-epub.xqm: unexpected token: refines (while expecting closing tag for element constructor: metadata) [at line 128, column 35]
```

… like `refines` was some special keyword for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a syntax error. If you want to return a sequence of elements (multiple elements) at one place, you have to wrap them in a sequence `(<foo/>, <bar/>, <batz/>)` instead of just listing them `<foo/><bar/><batz/>`. As is, after the `<dc:creator/>` element, the `else` statement is already expected.

Wrap the elements in a sequence, and watch out for the commas `,` separating the elements!

```
if ($authorGivenName)
then (
    <dc:creator id="author{$i}">{$authorGivenName || ' ' || $authorSurname}</dc:creator>,
    <meta refines="#author{$i}" property="file-as">{$authorSurname || ', ' $authorGivenName}</meta>,
    <meta refines="#author{$i}" property="role" scheme="marc:relators">aut</meta>,
    <meta refines="#author{$i}" property="role" scheme="onix:codelist17">A01</meta>
)
else ()
```

At the same time, the indentation puzzled me. Did you actually want to create the `<meta/>` elements as children of `<dc:creator/>`? If so, moving the closing tag after the `<meta/>` elements also fixes the issue, as you're only returning a single XML element (which child nodes).

```
if ($authorGivenName)
then
    <dc:creator id="author{$i}">{$authorGivenName || ' ' || $authorSurname}
        <meta refines="#author{$i}" property="file-as">{$authorSurname || ', ' $authorGivenName}</meta>,
        <meta refines="#author{$i}" property="role" scheme="marc:relators">aut</meta>,
        <meta refines="#author{$i}" property="role" scheme="onix:codelist17">A01</meta>
    </dc:creator>
else ()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right! As for the indentation, this is just a bad habit from manual ePub coding (meta refinements, of course, are not children of dc:creator elements). Thanks!